# how to view image in detailview controller in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsurlconnection

hi I'm developing a iOS which featuring  image updates. For using the  `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `setDatasource` to  bring the image to `tableview` with help of `php` and `json` now I'm trying give a detail view option for the my table view going as tough time in this can please help me.

the `setdatasource` coding the **imagecell.m**

```
-(void)setDataSource:(image *)inImageObj
{
     self.decriptionLabel.text = inImageObj.desp;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:inImageObj.img];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
     self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.responseData];
    self.thumbImageView.image = image;
}
```

this is code I used for view the images in table **view.m**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

   imgpoliticalCell *cell =(imgpoliticalCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if (cell== nil) {

    cell = [[imgpoliticalCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }
   [cell setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   return cell;
}
```

now I want view the image and description in the `detailviewcontroller`. I tried with segue i not able to get it properly

**detailviewcontroller.h** file

```
@interface DetailpoliticalViewController : UIViewController

    @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage * image;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * data;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *view;
```

this is code I have used in the **detailviewcontroller.m** file

```
@implementation DetailpoliticalViewController
@synthesize imageview,view;
@synthesize image,data;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.imageview.image = self.image;
     self.view.text= self.data;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
```

And this is the push segue code which I have used in the table view controller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detailsegue"]) {

    DetailpoliticalViewController *detailvc =(DetailpoliticalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.mytableview indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *) sender];
    image * eve = [imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [detailvc setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Now I'm not able to view the image and description in my detail view controller I'm getting the nil exception error

please can any one suggest some way to view the details

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.mytableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

instead of

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.mytableview indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *) sender];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing this two method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detailsegue" sender:indexPath];
}
```

and below method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detailsegue"]) {
        DetailpoliticalViewController *detailvc =(DetailpoliticalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        image * eve = [imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [detailvc setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"DetailSegue" sender: self];        

}

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
    DetailpoliticalViewController *detailvc =(DetailpoliticalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    image * eve = [imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [detailvc setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }
}
```

Check this tutorial [LINK 1](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-How-To-Display-Detail-Data-from-UITableView-in-Detail-View-Controller)